# Change names of a columns using a mapping file

Tags: shell, file, dictionary, unix, awk

I have a file with 3 columns like this:

```
NC_0001 10 x
NC_0001 11 x
NC_0002 90 y
```

I want to change the names of the first column using another file .txt that contains the conversion, it's like:

```
NC_0001 1
NC_0001 1
NC_0002 2
```

...

So finally I should have:

```
1 10 x
1 11 x
2 90 y
```

How can I do that?
P.S. the first file is very huge (50 GB) so I must use a unix command like awk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -f script.awk map_file data_file
```

```
NR == FNR {                  # for the first file
    tab[$1] = $2             # create a k/v of the colname and rename value
}

NR != FNR {                  # for the second file
    $1 = tab[$1]             # set first column equal to the map value
    print                    # print
}
```

As a one-liner

```
awk 'NR==FNR{t[$1]=$2} NR!=FNR{$1=t[$1];print}' map_file data_file
```

If possible, you should split the first file and run this command on each partition file in parallel. Then, join the results.

Comment: If I want to skip the first line for the data file I just use NR > 1. Where I should add this in the code ?

Comment: Just change the condition to `NR != FNR && FNR > 1`